# FTP upload using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am writing a code to upload a zip file to an ftp server. Surprisingly the code works fine for small files, but with bigger files I end up in problem. I am using Stream object and I have noted that my code is getting stuck while trying to close the Stream (only for big files). The code runs fine if I do not close the Stream (even for big files). Does anyone see any logic in why this is happening. And if I don't close the stream is it possible that I might end up in problem in future.

Code extract:

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(@"ftp://" + ftpServerIP + @"/" + fileInf.Name));
Stream strm = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();
```

The code stops responding (when the upload file is big) at:

```
strm.Close();
```

There is no exception as this part is within try-catch.

I don't know how to get a stack trace.

Comment: How are you using the FtWebRequest class? Do you have to problem with all FTP servers or just the one?

Comment: What do you mean by "end up in problem". Could you post a specific stack trace or incorrect behavior?

Comment: Sorry, if someone has edited my question, can you do that again please.

Comment: @abc Kobra is asking if there is a potential future problem if the stream is not closed - there is no stack trace.

Comment: Do you mean it hangs on the Close() line, or that an exception is thrown there? If the latter, you still need the stack trace; put some Debug statements in your catch block. If it's the former, you probably need to paste in more of your code.

Comment: How'd you end up correcting the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know specifically what error you're getting when closing the stream, but in our application, we do a lot of large file uploads (videos and images).  Here's how we write to our FTP stream:

```
request.KeepAlive = false; // This eliminated some of our stream closing problems

using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(file.Data, 0, file.Data.Length);
}
```

I thought that doing a `using` block would effectively do the `Close` call on its own, but maybe it also performs other necessary cleanup.  Also notice I turned off the FTP keepalives, which caused us problems in some of the third-party FTP sites we uploaded to.

You really should look at the specific exception you're receiving rather than swallowing all exceptions.  The error message will most-likely tell you what's wrong.  The most common problems we encountered had to do with active vs. passive mode and the keepalives.

**Edit:**

To discover what was really going on when we had FTP issues with CDNs (and it happens way too frequently), we sometimes had to turn tracing on in our application.  See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx) for details on how to enable tracing.  Another option is to use a tool like Wireshark to sniff the conversation between your application and the FTP server.  If you can see what's going in in the FTP protocol, you'll have a much better chance of resolving the issue.

Comment: Thanks. In my code KeepAlive is false and I tried "using", but the code never comes out of "using" block. Regarding errors, I don't get any exception, which is making it difficult to track the problem.

Comment: Are you using active or passive mode?

Comment: And when you say "There is no exception as this part is within try-catch," are you saying that the catch block isn't getting reached or that the try/catch is masking your exception?

Comment: I am using Passive mode. The catch block isn't getting reached.

Comment: Added some tips for diagnosing the problem in case it's an issue with the FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth a shot in trying out the Open Source FTP component from [here](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/overview.html)... I have tried using FtpWebRequest and my experience of using that was negative...slow, times out, <strike>because quite naturally, the FtpWebRequest works through port 80 instead of the native port 21</strike>...the situation changed quite dramatically when I used this FTP component, more versatile and powerful...

**Edit:** As ***Jacob*** pointed out my obvious error and my illogical view of the FtpWebRequest class which lead me to believe something funky and weird was going on, and that it was somehow doing something via HTTP ... Well Jacob must have a point...a classic case of bad naming convention within the Framework... Thanks Jacob!

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: FtpWebRequest has never used port 80 for us.  Where do you get this information from?

Comment: @Jacob: Why is it called FtpWebRequest...it is using the http protocol to communicate with an FTP server...the keyword is in the name!! Why use WebRequest to create an FtpWebRequest? If you disagree...why is there not a dedicated ftp component to communicate directly with port 21? It's wrapped around this WebRequest class...

Comment: It's just a bad name.  HttpWebRequest uses port 80, and FtpWebRequest uses port 21.  WebRequest is the abstract base class for both.

Comment: @Jacob: I was actually lead to believe there was something funky and weird going on as I found it too slow... lol...oh dear...will edit the answer to point out this ...